# Convert method from Java to Dart

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert valid IMEI generator from java to dart but i'm facing issues.
i try to use online tools but they didn't help me.
i try to re-write it in dart but i'm not getting any good result something with dart:math is not working...

what i'm missing?

this is the original java:

```
class IMEI {
    public static String generateIMEINumber() {
        int pos;
        int[] str = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int sum = 0;
        int final_digit;
        int t;
        int len_offset;
        int len = 15;

        //
        // Fill in the first two values of the string based with the specified prefix.
        // Reporting Body Identifier list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporting_Body_Identifier
        //

        String[] rbi = new String[] { "01", "10", "30", "33", "35", "44", "45", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "86", "91", "98", "99" };
        String[] arr = rbi[((Double) Math.floor(Math.random() * rbi.length)).intValue()].split("(?!^)");
        str[0] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        str[1] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        pos = 2;

        //
        // Fill all the remaining numbers except for the last one with random values.
        //

        while (pos < len - 1) {
            str[pos++] = ((Double) Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).intValue() % 10;
        }

        //
        // Calculate the Luhn checksum of the values thus far.
        //

        len_offset = (len + 1) % 2;
        for (pos = 0; pos < len - 1; pos++) {
            if ((pos + len_offset) % 2 == 1) {
                t = str[pos] * 2;
                if (t > 9) {
                    t -= 9;
                }
                sum += t;
            } else {
                sum += str[pos];
            }
        }

        //
        // Choose the last digit so that it causes the entire string to pass the checksum.
        //

        final_digit = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
        str[len - 1] = final_digit;

        return intArrayToStr(str);
    }

    private static String intArrayToStr(int[] arr) {
        if (null == arr || 0 == arr.length) return "";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
        sb.append(arr[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) sb.append(arr[i]);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempt at converting that and please only include the specific part you are having issues with. Otherwise, it will be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the java code to dart.
But changed regex because not working.
I'm not sure everything is correct.

```
String generateIMEINumber() {
  int pos;
  var str = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  var sum = 0;
  var finalDigit;
  var t;
  var lenOffset;
  var len = 15;

  //
  // Fill in the first two values of the string based with the specified prefix.
  // Reporting Body Identifier list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporting_Body_Identifier
  //

  var rbi = [
    '01',
    '10',
    '30',
    '33',
    '35',
    '44',
    '45',
    '49',
    '50',
    '51',
    '52',
    '53',
    '54',
    '86',
    '91',
    '98',
    '99'
  ];

  var exp = RegExp(r'\d');

  var str1 = rbi[(Random().nextDouble() * rbi.length).floorToDouble().toInt()];

  var arr = exp.allMatches(str1).map((e) => e.group(0)).toList();
  str[0] = int.parse(arr[0]);
  str[1] = int.parse(arr[1]);
  pos = 2;

  //
  // Fill all the remaining numbers except for the last one with random values.
  //

  while (pos < len - 1) {
    str[pos++] = (Random().nextDouble() * 10).floorToDouble().toInt() % 10;
  }

  //
  // Calculate the Luhn checksum of the values thus far.
  //

  lenOffset = (len + 1) % 2;
  for (pos = 0; pos < len - 1; pos++) {
    if ((pos + lenOffset) % 2 == 1) {
      t = str[pos] * 2;
      if (t > 9) {
        t -= 9;
      }
      sum += t;
    } else {
      sum += str[pos];
    }
  }

  //
  // Choose the last digit so that it causes the entire string to pass the checksum.
  //

  finalDigit = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
  str[len - 1] = finalDigit;

  return intArrayToStr(str);
}

String intArrayToStr(List<int> arr) {
  if (null == arr || arr.isEmpty) return '';

  var buffer = StringBuffer();
  buffer.write(arr[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    buffer.write(arr[i]);
  }

  return buffer.toString();
}
```

[Run on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b3db101b29a9b41a37c0a71446c3171a)